# How do I specify advanced power settings for all users using group policy?

Tags: windows-10, power-management, group-policy

I need to set up a Microsoft Surface Pro tablet so that it never throttles the CPU. One solution I found using [this guide](http://forums.windowscentral.com/microsoft-surface-pro-4/403403-no-more-throttle-fans-surface-pro-3-4-a.html) is to set both minimum and maximum processor state to 100% in both battery and plugged-in modes.

However, since I need to apply this setting to about a hundred of tablets I would like to do so using group policy. However in there I can only find power settings concerning screen saver.